# Adding a new row at bottom as last row of grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I need to add a row to the grid which is already having data.when i add a new row, right now it is adding at the top i.e as first record of the grid but i need to add the row at the bottom of grid as last record to the grid.How to achieve this?can any one help please?

Thanks,

Comment: why do you need to do this? If you have to, why not add it to the data you use to populate the grid?

Comment: add editor is coming for grid on the top row that i need to show it on bottom

Comment: why not add it to the control tab above the grid?

Comment: not the add control , im talking about after clicking the add control  empty row with columns  to enter data to add a new row to the grid

Comment: oh, i get you, is there a reason why you dont want it at the top or is it just for cosmetics?

Comment: yes just for cosmetics only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138122/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-raghus).

Answer (score 0):

Kendo has a config option where you specify if you want the new row at top or at bottom. So to answer your question the object would look like:

```
{
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  editable: {
    createAt: "bottom"
  },
  toolbar: ["create"]
}
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/editable.createat

Comment: This answer is applicable only to Kendo for jQuery, not Kendo for Angular